# Does RawSocket in Dart allow to send and receive directly IP packets?

Tags: dart

As I know [raw socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_socket) allows to send and receive IP packets without any specific transport layer protocol.

Dart's "dart:io" comes with [RawSocket](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.23.0/dart-io/RawSocket-class.html) class defined as a low-level interface to a socket (maybe they mean TCP socket).

My question is does Dart's RawSocket allow to directly send and receive IP packets? if not, is there're any way to do so in Dart?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no possible way to directly send and receive IP packets in Dart. [RawSocket](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.23.0/dart-io/RawSocket-class.html) and its variants shouldn't be confused with what are known as raw sockets, as they just expose raw events signaled by the system. The fact that these socket classes have the Raw prefix is just the result of an unfortunate naming choice.