# How can I get a local device's IP knowing its MAC? (ARP request)

Tags: flutter

For my use case, I need to find a device's IP on my local network, knowing only its MAC address (ARP request). There was no way (that I'm aware of) to do that in android sdk, so I ended up scanning the whole IP range.

Is there a way, with flutter, to recover a device's IP knowing its MAC, or will I have to scan IP like in android sdk? 
Can I access the phone's arp table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't send IP packets with Dart according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44621512/does-rawsocket-in-dart-allow-to-send-and-receive-directly-ip-packets).

> Can I access the phone's arp table?

You can use `Process` class to call `arp` commands. It will probably requeire root acces.